# About Theorem 17.4's proof of Munkres's Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

> **Theorem 17.4** 
> Let *Y*  be a subspace of *X*; let *A* be a subset of *Y*; let $\overline{A}$ denote the
> closure of *A* in *X*. Then the closure of *A* in *Y* equals $\overline{A}$ ∩ *Y*. 
> *Proof.* Let B denote the closure of A in *Y*. The set $\overline{A}$ is closed in *X*, so $\overline{A}$ ∩ *Y* is
> closed in *Y* by Theorem 17.2. Since $\overline{A}$ ∩ *Y* contains A, and since by definition B equals
> the intersection of all closed subsets of *Y* containing A, we must have B ⊂ ($\overline{A}$ ∩ *Y* ).
> On the other hand, we know that B is closed in *Y*. Hence by **Theorem 17.2**,
> B = C ∩ *Y* for some set C closed in X. Then C is a closed set of *X* containing A;
> because $\overline{A}$ is the intersection of all such closed sets, we conclude that $\overline{A}$ ⊂ C. Then
> ($\overline{A}$ ∩ *Y* ) ⊂ (C ∩ *Y* ) = B.

> **Theorem 17.2** 
> Let *Y* be a subspace of *X*. Then a set *A* is closed in *Y* if and only if
> it equals the intersection of a closed set of *X* with *Y*.

Well, I am studying Topology from Munkres's Topology, and I am stuck here.

1. What is the definition of the closure of A in a subspace *Y* ? In my intuition, the closure of A in a topological space *X* is "the smallest" closed set that exists in *X* and contains A.
2. (What has really confused me) I couldn't understand "Then C is a closed set of *X* containing A" in the proof of **Theorem 17.4**. I know that C contains B, or C contains A ∩ *Y*, but I don't know anything about C ∩ (*X\Y*), for me, C ∩ (*X\Y*) could not contain A ∩ (*X\Y*).

Comment: Y is a subspace of X, it means Y is equipped with the topology induced from X. A is a subset of Y, so the closure of A in Y is defined in the normal sense, i.e. closure in a topological space. Your 2nd question concerns the definition of topological subspace, i.e., what is an open set in Y? A closed subset in Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site. See the [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some help with the formatting.

> 1. What is the definition of the closure of $A$ in a subspace $Y$?

$Y$ forms a topological (sub)space. We can "forget" about $X$ and just ask the question: for a subset $A\subseteq Y$, what is the topological closure of $A$? This is all considered in the subspace topology of $Y$. There are many ways to define closure, the simplest being: $$\mathrm{cl}_Y(A):=\bigcap_{K:A\subseteq K\text{ and $K$ is closed in $Y$}}K$$Notice that $K$ being closed in $Y$ is not necessarily the same thing as $K$ being closed in $X$, so a priori the closure of $A$ in $Y$ is different to the closure of $A$ in $X$. In case I'm just rambling, let me reiterate that the definition is simply the same as the usual definition of closure, applied to the subspace topology of $Y$.

> 2. [why does $C$ contain $A$?]

Your doubt is reasonable if $A$ is some 'arbitrary' subset of $X$. However, it says at the start that $A\subseteq Y$; $C$ contains $A\cap Y$ - as you say - but since $A\cap Y=A$, that just means: $C$ contains $A$.

Comment: Understood. I just have one more question. If A ∩ (X\Y) is not empty, i.e. A isn´t a subset of Y (what I initially thought), is that definition of clY(A) still valid? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @TYFIRE You're welcome. If $A$ is not a subset of $Y$ it doesn't make as much sense to ask about its closure in $Y$ (because it "does not live in" $Y$, why would you care about its closure in $Y$?). You *could* define, the closure of $A$ in $Y$ is $A\cup\mathrm{cl}_Y(A\cap Y)$. I've never seen anyone do this but it's arguably a good concept